# Updating empty value in database

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using angular CLI 8.1.0. I have list of users on mat table. When i click on any user the new page is opened . That page contains 2 buttons "approve" and "reject" when i click on approve the column should be updated from "pending" to "approve" for that particular user. But it's updating column with empty value. 
Here i am attaching my code. Can anyone help please.

> index.php

```
<?php

    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","angdb");

    $request=$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

    $data=array();
    switch($request)
    {
        case 'GET':
            response(getData());
            break;

        case 'PUT':
            response(updateData());

        default:
            #code...
            break;
    }

    function getData()
    {
        global $conn;

        if(@$_GET['id'])
        {
            @$id=$_GET['id'];

            $where="AND id=".$id;
        }
        else
        {
            $id=0;
            $where="";
        }


        $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from vendor where status='pending' ".$where);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            $data[]=array("id"=>$row['id'],"changeColumn"=>$row['changeColumn'],"type"=>$row['type'],"timestamp"=>$row['timestamp'],"status"=>$row['status'],"name"=>$row['name']);
        }
        return $data;
    }

    function updateData()
    {
        global $conn;
        parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'),$_PUT);

        if(@$_GET['id'])
        {
            @$id=$_GET['id'];

            $where="where id=".$id;
        }
        else
        {
            $id=0;
            $where="";
        }

        $query=mysqli_query($conn,"update vendor set status='".$_PUT['status']."'".$where);

        if($query==true)
        {
            $data[]=array("Message"=>"Updated");
        }
        else
        {
            $data[]=array("Message"=>"Not updated");
        }
        return $data;
    }

    function response($data)
    {
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
?>
```

> api.service.ts

```
updateById(id,payload)
{
   let url = `http://localhost/angular_admin/php/index.php?id=${id}`
   return this.httpClient.put(url, payload);
}
```

> approval.component.ts

```
approve() {
    this.apiService.updateById(this.id, {status:'approve'})
    .subscribe((data:any)=> {
        if (data.Message == "Updated") { // check if the result is sucess then navigat to
            this.router.navigate(["/home/vendor-action"]);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you'd better rework all of your server code. it's totally vulnerable against sql injections.

Comment: @MarkusDresch actully i am new in angular and PHP, and now i am at learning stage that's why don't know all these concepts. Do you have solution for my query?

Comment: log the contents of $_PUT to debug.

Comment: ERROR 
HttpErrorResponse
defaultErrorLogger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query of php file use get method because browser uses get method

```
function updateData()
{
    global $conn;
    parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'),$_PUT);

    if(@$_GET['id'])
    {
        @$id=$_GET['id'];

        $where="where id=".$id;
    }
    else
    {
        $id=0;
        $where="";
    }

    $query=mysqli_query($conn,"update vendor set status='".$_GET['status']."'".$where);

    if($query==true)
    {
        $data[]=array("Message"=>"Updated");
    }
    else
    {
        $data[]=array("Message"=>"Not updated");
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I definitely agree that you need to improve the design and please try to come up with a specific problem. It is very difficult to tell what is the issue in code.

Please try below code let us know if still facing issue. I have added console and echo for testing purpose, you can remove them later

```js
approval.component.ts

approve() {
    this.apiService.updateById({id: this.id, status:'approve'})
    .subscribe((data:any)=> {
      console.log('data loaded successfully');
        if (data.Message == "Updated") { // check if the result is sucess then navigat to
            this.router.navigate(["/home/vendor-action"]);
        }
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}

api.service.ts

updateById(payload)
{
   let url = `http://localhost/angular_admin/php/index.php?id=${id}`
   return this.httpClient.put(payload);
}


index.php

function updateData()
    {
        global $conn;
        parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'),$_PUT);
        
        $status = $_PUT['status'];
        $id = $_PUT['id'];
        
        $sql = "UPDATE vendor SET status=".$status." WHERE id=".$id.";

        $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if($query==true)
        {
            $data[]=array("Message"=>"Updated");
        }
        else
        {
            $data[]=array("Message"=>"Not updated");
        }
        return $data;
    }
```